# How to use ST-LINK Utility

Tags: stm32, st-link

[image]

Could someone be kind to explain some features inside ST-Link Utility.

1. What is the unit of measurement for size, how it works?
2. What does represent data width?
3. Changing data width presents different view in box 3, how does this display works and what does it show?
4. How does the memory address scheme works in box 4? (it looks like it increments in value of 16 but why?)

Looking through ST-Link pdf documentation didn't gave much information about it.

Thank for helping out in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just from looking at it for a few minutes,

1. Size - The number of bytes in the hex file. Changing the number doesn't seem to do anything..
2. Data Width - Changes the representation in the columns of the data display, from 8-bit bytes to 32-bit words. Seems to do nothing else.
3. See #2. Additionally, the 32-bit display turns the byte order around into a more readable [big-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) format for every 32-bit word. (the memory is organized in little-endian, obviously)
4. That is the address of the data in the first column. You can see that there are 16 bytes displayed (or 4 32-bit words depending on the Data Width setting). If you take the first number, 0x08000000 and add 16 to it, you get 0x08000010 in hexadecimal, which is the second row's starting address and heading.